# Area under a cycloid

Tags: parametric, cycloid

If the length of the cycloid is $4$ times the diameter of a rotating circle, then the area under the arch traced out by that cycloid is how many times the area of the rotating circle?

I tried using the parametric equations for a cycloid: $x = a(t-\sin{t})$, and $y = a(1-\cos{t})$.

The answer is three. Can someone please explain this? I am preferably looking for an answer that does not involve calculus.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid#Area

Comment: See http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/cmj_ftp/CMJ/January%202010/3%20Articles/3%20Martin/08-170.pdf

Comment: See the book New Horizons in Geometry by Tom Apostol and Mamikon A Mnatskanian for several innovative uses of tangent sweep theorem.

Answer (score 1):

To use the parametric equation:

Render the area as $\int y dx$ between the appropriate limits, which are clearly from $t=0$ to $t=2\pi$.  Plug in the parametric equations to get

$a^2\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos t)d(t-\sin t)$

To get an integral with just $dt$ differentiate the $t-\sin t$ function and combine the derivative with the preexisting factor $1-\cos t$.  Thus

$a^2\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos t)^2dt$

This may be simplified by putting in $(1-\cos t)^2=1-2\cos t+\cos^2t$ and then $\cos^2 t=(1+\cos 2t)/2$.  Then the cosine integrate to zero over full periods, allowing those terms to be canceled out and leaving just a constant ($3/2$) remaining in the inte-grand.  Thus the final answer $3\pi a^2$ where the parametric equations had defined $a$ as the radius.